# Ropsten Block Height is different than Block Height on local GETH instance

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, geth-debugging

I am running a GETH instance on my machine

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --ipcpath /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303" --verbosity=6 --port "30303" --networkid 3
```

The Block height on Ropsten currently is `Block 3454032`

When I call `eth.syncing` from my console I get

`currentBlock: 2848357,
  highestBlock: 3093429,
  knownStates: 6039183,
  pulledStates: 6039183,
  startingBlock: 2847921`

highestBlock on mine reads lower than what Ropsten is displaying. Is the going to be a problem when the sync is completed at `3093429` and Ropsten is at `3454032`?

Am I about to find out after 2 days of syncing it was all for nothing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as `eth.syncing` doesn't show `false` your geth node is under syncing process, you need to wait.

Comment: I understand that it must wait to sync, are you saying the height displayed on my view locally is incorrect? and that it just needs to sync no matter what that numbers says? If that is a true that seems like a bug to me where block height is displayed incorrectly.

Comment: The info from `eth.syncing` not supose to be true, it's changed while your node does sync, you need to wait, there is no ETA, it can be an hour or a day.

Comment: Thanks. Mine is on day 3, here is my net speed:

Selecting best server based on latency...
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 302.30 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 232.94 Mbit/s